# how many times input splits are replicated in hdfs

Tags: mapreduce

each Input split is replicated in 3 times in hadoop cluster. for each replicate split , does hadoop assigns each map? . If then assign which map results send to reduce function. does hadoop replicates the reduce function also

Answer (score 1):

No, Even though there are three replicas for a split, only one mapper will be assigned by MapReduce engine. It uses the concept called **data localization** in order to decide which replica of the split to use.

> Hadoop does its best to run the map task on a node where the input
>   data resides in HDFS.     This is called the data locality
>   optimization since it doesn’t use valuable cluster bandwidth.
>   Sometimes, however, all three nodes hosting the HDFS block replicas
>   for a map task’s input split are running other map tasks so the job
>   scheduler will look for a free map slot on a node in the same rack as
>   one of the blocks. Very occasionally even this is not possible, so an
>   off-rack node is used, which results in an inter-rack network transfer.

Please find below the excerpts from the Hadoop Definitive guide.

> Hadoop divides the input to a MapReduce job into fixed-size pieces
>   called input splits, or just splits. Hadoop creates one map task for
>   each split, which runs the user- defined map function for each record
>   in the split.